# How to get the largest and smallest of 3 values with fewest comparisons?

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is a simple introduction course question. I have to write a program that asks the user to input 3 numbers, and determines the largest and smallest number.

I need to only use `if` statements.

This is what I tried so far: which required 4 comparisons.

```
int x, y, z;
int smallest, largest; 
cout << "Please enter 3 numbers to compare: " ;
cin >> x >> y >> z;

smallest = x;
largest = x;

if (y > largest) 
        largest = y;
if (z > largest)
        largest = z;
if (y < smallest)
        smallest = y;
if (z < smallest)
        smallest = z;

cout << "largest: " << largest << ", and smallest: " << smallest << endl;
```

My question is: Is it possible to only use 3 comparisons, or less? I think when `y > largest`, it also tells us something else as well?

Comment: tip: bubblesort would only be three comparisons, and would tell you the min and max.

Comment: Actually, bubblesort normally does swaps so it would be more complex than some of the answers.  [But here's an unrolled inlined bubblesort!](http://ideone.com/SGiYGu)

Comment: `auto [smallest, largest] = std::minmax({x, y, z})` promises merely "no more than 4" comparisons

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you toss out a lot of information. In "challenges" such as these, you have to make the most of what you have. So when you say, for example

```
if (y > largest)
```

don't just treat the `true` case. Also try to reason about the case when the condition doesn't hold.

```
if ( x < y )
{
    smallest = x;
    biggest = y;
}
else
{
    smallest = y;
    biggest = x;
}

if ( z < smallest )
   smallest = z;
else if ( z > biggest )
   biggest = z;
```

This contains only 3 comparisons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if z is biggest three comparisons get executed.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't know if it matters, but if it is only `if statement`, no `else statement`. Can it also be done in 3 comparison?

Comment: @George the `else` **is part** of the `if` statement.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I know, but that's because this question came in the chapter before the book teaches `else` statement, I was just wondering.

Comment: @George: If your exercise is limited to that, just put the first `else` part before the `if` (so it gets executed every time, but if the `if` condition is true, the values are overwritten), and drop the other `else` which is just an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you checking `if (y < smallest)`? At this point in the flow, `smallest` must be `x`, but you've already checked if `y > x` in the first condition (`if (y > largest)`), so the third condition is redundant.

Comment: Sure, just start with `largest = y` instead of `largest = x` and see where it takes you...

Answer (score 1):

The question is finding the largest or smallest by only if else statements, and we have three variables to use, so we only need two comparisons.

```
{
    int valueOne,
    valueTwo,
    valueThree,
    smallest;

//User input for valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree.

smallest = valueOne;

if (smallest < valueTwo)
{
smallest = valueTwo;
}
if (smallest < valueThree)
{
smallest = valueThree;
}

//No matter what happens, smallest will have the smallest value now.

//Use >, rather than <, and "largest" rather than "smallest" for finding largest value.

//With this logic, you always will have one less comparison than the total number or variables to compare

//i.e. 7 variables means 6 comparisons.

//This contains only 2 comparisons.
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can determine a sort for three numbers `x`, `y`, and `z` using at most 3 comparisons:

```
if (x < y)
    if (y < z)
       //x,y,z -> x min
    else if (x < z)
       //x,z,y -> x min
    else
       //z,x,y -> z min
else
    if (z >= x)
       //y,x,z -> y min
    else if (z >= y)
       //y,z,x -> y min
    else
       //z,y,x -> z min
```

So getting the min can also be done with 3 comparisons.

---

You can get the min in 2 comparisons by doing:

```
m = x;
m = min(m,y);
m = min(m,z);
```

where `min(a,b)` is `a < b ? a : b`.

---

In general you can get the min of N numbers using N - 1 comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I find this easiest to understand for you.

```
a = 5;
b = 10;
c = 15;

//FIND MAX
if (a >= b && a >= c)
{
   max = a;

} else
{
    if (b >= c)
        max = b
    else
        max = c;
}

//FIND MIN
if (a <= b && a <= c)
{

    min = a;
} else
{
    if (b <=c)
        min = b;
    else
        min = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is just for fun and I believe the `myabs` function is actually supposed to be undefined behaviour, but I've only ever seen places that it works as expected.

```
    double myabs(double x)
    {
        int64_t * p = (int64_t*)&x;
        //clear sign bit
        *p &= 0x7fffffffffffffff;
        return x;
    }

    int main()
    {
        double x = 0, y = 1, z = 2;
        //find max/min of first two numbers
        double min = (myabs(x+y)-myabs(x-y))/2;
        double max = (myabs(x+y)+myabs(x-y))/2;
        //find max/min of previous max/min and third number
        min = (myabs(min+z) - myabs(min-z))/2;
        max = (myabs(max+z) + myabs(max-z))/2;
        std::cout << min << ' ' << max << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Which outputs `0 2` correctly with 0 comparisons in total.

Comment: It works only if `long` is 64bit. Not too many places where it will work. I never saw such places, for example

Comment: @kotlomoy `long` is 64 bits on Linux, but not Windows.  There are defines for different data types for Windows that you can use instead.  I'm not sure what it is offhand though.

Comment: @kotlomoy changed `long` to `int64_t` defined in `stdint.h`.  That should make it work on Windows as well (not that I'm able to test that, however)

Comment: Preferrably `<cstdint>` instead of `<stdint.h>`, since this is a C++ question.

Comment: `<cstdint>` is actually c++11, it was actually the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    int numb1, numb2, numb3;
    if(numb1>numb2 && numb1>numb3){ 
        printf("%d is largest.\n%d is smallest.", numb1, numb2<numb3? numb2:numb3);
    }
    else if(numb2>numb1 && numb2>numb3){ 
        printf("%d is largest.\n%d is smallest.", numb2, numb1<numb3? numb1:numb3);
    }
    else{ 
        printf("%d is largest.\n%d is smallest.", numb3, numb1<numb2? numb1:numb2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a; int b; int c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;

if ( a > b && b > c ){ cout << a << " MAIXM \n" << b << " MEDIU \n" << c << " MINIM \n"; }

if ( b > a && a > c ){ cout << b << " MAIXM \n" << a << " MEDIU \n" << c << " MINIM \n"; }

if ( c > b && b > a ){ cout << c << " MAIXM \n" << b << " MEDIU \n" << a << " MINIM \n"; }

if ( a > c && c > b ){ cout << a << " MAIXM \n" << c << " MEDIU \n" << b << " MINIM \n"; }

if ( b > c && c > a ){ cout << b << " MAIXM \n" << c << " MEDIU \n" << a << " MINIM \n"; }

if ( c > a && a > b ){ cout << c << " MAIXM \n" << a << " MEDIU \n" << b << " MINIM \n"; }
```